# Need to send [syn, ack ] packet over TCP

Tags: c#, tcp, handshake

I need to make my PC reply to a windows application which is sending [SYN] packet constantly and expecting [SYN, ACK] from my PC. My goal is to record messages received from that application using wireshark. For that I need to write an application which can send reply to that PC. I am not experienced in TCP protocol, so need suggestions how can I send [SYN, ACK] reply with some C# code?
[Wireshark Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcG32.png)

```
namespace TCP_CLIENT
{
    class Program
    {
        const int PORT_NO = 5000;
        const string SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.100";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //---listen at the specified IP and port no.---
            IPAddress localAdd = IPAddress.Parse(SERVER_IP);
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(localAdd, PORT_NO);
            Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
            listener.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use one of the Microsoft Example for Sockets.  You need   Server application.  The code uses Sockets but you can use any class the inherits the Socket Like TCPListener.

Comment: I have written server code but it keeps listening only. How to send SYN, ACK? The code is updated in the question

Comment: SYN and ACK are automatically sent by the Ethernet interface when using TCP.  You are getting re-transmissions because you are not listening to the same IP/Port that is being sent.  You are listening to port 5000 while the client is sending to 5099.

Comment: @jdweng If so please check the code in question, my code just keeps listening..

Comment: Change your port to 5099.

Comment: Sorry for bad formatting I don't know why its not working

Comment: @jdweng Thanks let me ceck

Comment: I would also listen to at IP : IPAddress localAdd = IPAddress.Any;

Comment: Did it, but no SYN, ACK received. '           //---listen at the specified IP and port no.---
            IPAddress localAdd = IPAddress.Parse(SERVER_IP);
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5099);
            Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
            listener.Start();
'

Comment: The Listener must be started before client.   You need to block.  The program is closing.  So add to end of program Console.ReadLine(); Post new Wireshark results after restarting.  To make sure you are listen you can use following from cmd.exe : >Netstat -a